# Get Eclipse IDE to show version of Java RE it's using

Tags: eclipse, java

I've just installed proper JRE rather than the OpenJDK, I was wondering if there is an easy way to find out which RE Eclipse is using?  Maybe in a help menu or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. The checked JRE is the one which Eclipse uses by default. This JRE is used to compile and run the code.

The JRE used by Eclipse to run itself is the either the one specified in the `eclipse.ini` or the `java` executable in your system path. From the [Eclipse docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?):

> Find the JVM
>
> If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use
>   it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the
>   system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable.
>
> To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the -vm
>   command line argument:
>
> eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe ''start Java by executing the specified java executable
>   eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll ''start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process

Comment: Edited the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know what JDK is being used to execute Eclipse: Help, About Eclipse SDK, Installation Details, tab Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Go to Window/Preferences/Installed JREs, then choose one that you prefer.

You can also choose JRE on project level. Open project properties and choose "Java compiler". Then you can configure different JRE for specific project.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know which version Eclipse uses to execute itself.

It would simply run with the same JRE that would execute when you issue `java` from command line.

You can modify `-vm` param in your `eclipse.ini` file to run with some other JRE e.g.:

```
-vm
c:/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin
```