# How to check for the JRE version in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

How to check which version of `JRE` the eclipse is using ?

This section :

Window--->Preferences--->Java

shows by the name of JDK :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-installed_jres.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Eclipse IDE to show version of Java RE it's using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573508/get-eclipse-ide-to-show-version-of-java-re-its-using)

Answer (score 18):

Open the About Eclipse dialog (Help -> About Eclipse on Windows, Eclipse -> About Eclipse on OS X)

[image: About Eclipse dialog]

Click "Installation Details", choose the Configuration tab, and scroll down to the "java.home" entry.  The value is the path name to the JVM used.

[image]

Comment: In the tab that I have shown in the picture, why does it show `jdk` under the `jre` tab ? Value in home variable `java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9/jre`

Comment: JDK's include JRE's.  And the public source which Eclipse knows how to use.

Answer (score 6):

To see which Java Eclipse itself is using go to `Help > About Eclipse` click `Installation Details` and look at the `Configuration` tab.

When you run Java programs from Eclipse you can select which Java is used. `Preferences > Installed JREs` lists the JREs (and JDKs) that Eclipse knows about.  The `Run Configuration` for the program shows which Java is used to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Window->Preference->Installed JRES

or Goto Project , right click 
 Preference -> Jva Build Path -> libraries

Comment: But it lists by the name JDK http://s29.postimg.org/lk77yorev/Screenshot_at_2014_03_13_22_20_57.png

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following figure.

[image: click on Run from menu bar ->select Run Configuration]

[image: Select JRE on tab]

Comment: under my _jre_ tab, I see this http://s13.postimg.org/rk1ljg4dj/Screenshot_at_2014_03_13_22_30_19.png It says `JDK`

Comment: please click the Alternate JRE radio button

Comment: This does not guarantee to tell which JVM Eclipse uses itself.

Comment: @ Suhail Gupta -> Some of the jdk include the jre

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen -> Hello, yes this is not guarantee but it can know the jre version so I suggested this. Thank you for your comment.