# GUI behaves differently in IDE vs command line

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a GUI application in Java, and using Eclipse. However, the result of the code behaves differently when I compile and run using command line vs in the IDE itself. Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;

public class MainGUI extends Application
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
     primaryStage.setTitle("Citation Machine");
     GridPane grid1 = new GridPane();
     grid1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
     grid1.setHgap(10);
     grid1.setVgap(10);
     grid1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
     Label l = new Label("Welcome. Please enter your URL.");
     grid1.add(l, 0, 0);
     TextField urlField = new TextField();
     grid1.add(urlField, 0, 1);
     Button submit = new Button("OK");
     submit.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(urlField.getText()));
     grid1.add(submit, 1, 1);

     GridPane grid = new GridPane();
     grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
     grid.setHgap(10);
     grid.setVgap(10);
     grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
     Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
     scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
     grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

     Label titleLabel = new Label("Article Title:");
     grid.add(titleLabel, 0, 1);

     TextField title = new TextField();
     grid.add(title, 1, 1);

     Label authorLabel = new Label("Author:");
     grid.add(authorLabel, 0, 2);

     TextField author = new TextField();
     grid.add(author, 1, 2);

     Label webTitleLabel = new Label("Website Title:");
     grid.add(webTitleLabel, 0, 3 );

     TextField webTitle = new TextField();
     grid.add(webTitle, 1, 3);

     Label publisherLabel = new Label("Website Publisher:");
     grid.add(publisherLabel, 0, 4);

     TextField publisher = new TextField();
     grid.add(publisher, 1, 4);

     Label urlLabel = new Label("URL:");
     grid.add(urlLabel, 0, 5);

     TextField url = new TextField();
     grid.add(url, 1, 5);

     Label monthLabel = new Label("Month of Publication:");
     grid.add(monthLabel, 0, 6);

     TextField month = new TextField();
     grid.add(month, 1, 6);

     Label dayLabel = new Label("Day of Publication");
     grid.add(dayLabel, 0, 7);

     TextField day = new TextField();
     grid.add(day, 1, 7);

     Label yearLabel = new Label("Year of Publication:");
     grid.add(yearLabel, 0, 8);

     TextField year = new TextField();
     grid.add(year, 1, 8);

   //  grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
     Scene urlChecker = new Scene(grid1, 300, 150);
     Scene information = new Scene(grid, 400, 500);
     primaryStage.setScene(urlChecker);
     primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

When I compile and run through CL, it works as expected, printing "pressed" to the CL when the button is clicked. When I run it through the IDE, nothing happens. Why does this occur?

Comment: is a different Java version associated with the IDE compared to the command line?

Comment: @brw59 how would I check that?

Comment: Convert your lambda expression to a method so you can set a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Works fine for me, using Eclipse. Most likely explanation is that the project needs rebuilding, and it's somehow running an old version of the project which was compiled before you added the button handler. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project in your IDE.

Comment: to check version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385457/how-to-check-for-the-jre-version-in-eclipse

Comment: @James_D I cleaned it and tried running it again, but it gives me a ClassNotFound exception.

Comment: What class can't it find?

Comment: @James_D MainGUI

Comment: Sounds like you cleaned the project but it hasn't been rebuilt. Is it set to build automatically?

Comment: @James_D It might not be set to rebuild automatically. How would I rebuild?

Comment: I don't even know which IDE you are using.

Comment: @James_D It actually is set to build automatically, my bad.

Comment: @James_D Eclipse

Comment: Well, if it can't find your main class, it clearly isn't built.... Try unchecking "Build Automatically" from the Project menu, then choose "Build Project" to force a build...

Comment: @James_D I did that, it still throws the same exception

Comment: Something is seriously messed up in your project configuration if it can't find the class you're trying to execute after building. Check through the build configurations and run configurations to make sure everything makes sense.